# How to create VMs using google compute engine REST API

Tags: c#, rest, google-api, google-compute-engine

I am new to Google Compute Engine. Some one please help me with creating Google Compute Engine VMs programmatically using REST APIs in C#.

Comment: See [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25770052/3618671) which has an answer with some links.

Answer (score 1):

Here [1] you can found the API documentation to create an instance and at the bottom of the document the C# examples [2]:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Compute.v1;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Data = Google.Apis.Compute.v1.Data;

namespace ComputeSample
{
    public class ComputeExample
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ComputeService computeService = new ComputeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = GetCredential(),
                ApplicationName = "Google-ComputeSample/0.1",
            });

            // Project ID for this request.
            string project = "my-project";  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

            // The name of the zone for this request.
            string zone = "my-zone";  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

            // TODO: Assign values to desired properties of `requestBody`:
            Data.Instance requestBody = new Data.Instance();

            InstancesResource.InsertRequest request = computeService.Instances.Insert(requestBody, project, zone);

            // To execute asynchronously in an async method, replace `request.Execute()` as shown:
            Data.Operation response = request.Execute();
            // Data.Operation response = await request.ExecuteAsync();

            // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));
        }

        public static GoogleCredential GetCredential()
        {
            GoogleCredential credential = Task.Run(() => GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefaultAsync()).Result;
            if (credential.IsCreateScopedRequired)
            {
                credential = credential.CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform");
            }
           return credential;
        }
    }
}
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert
[2] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert#examples

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)